# Does anyone know how this kind of pixelated type is created?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typefaces, pixel, posters

Does anyone know how this type is created? Not sure what it would be called, pixelated? Been noticing it in a lot of posters

[image]

Comment: Some of it looks similar to ascii art text: [Figlet font Bloody](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Bloody&t=Type%20Something%20), [Figlet font ANSI Shadow](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=ANSI%20Shadow&t=Type%20Something%20), [Figlet font Delta Corps Priest 1](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Delta%20Corps%20Priest%201&t=Type%20Something%20), [Figlet font Electric](http://patorjk.com/software/taag/#p=display&f=Electronic&t=Type%20Something%20) — Bloody is the closest. The rest I picked just cause they kinda sorta had the same feel....

Answer (score 1):

This is what one can get in Photoshop without asking: Pixelated text but not blurred because anti-aliasing is OFF:

[image]

It was written into an image which has width only about 200 pixels. Anti-aliasing is turned OFF by right clicking the text object in the layers panel and selecting A-A =None.

That text can be enlargened to bigger pixel dimensions without losing the pixelation:

- rasterize the type
- scale the whole image to bigger size, use resampling method = Nearest neighbour

[image]

The pixelated extrusions without having a ready to use font for it need some tinkering. You can paste the enlargened shape to Illustrator an trace it to a vector shape. Give to it after tracing a color. I gave light grey. Then add effect Extrude & Bevel:

[image]

After expanding the appearance you can make edits such as giving a stroke:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I normally use a font called 04b21

[image]

You can download it here: https://www.fontspace.com/04/04b21