# Font text is not smooth in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text

Has anyone dealt with this issue before? For some reason, my text on Photoshop is not smooth at all, no matter what font is picked.

Example:
[image]

If anyone has any tips, would be highly recommended.

Comment: There are others who want this, see:  https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117957/does-anyone-know-how-this-kind-of-pixelated-type-is-created There' s an explanation, too.

Comment: I don't want it tho, I want to get rid of it and have smooth text.

Comment: So put anti-aliasing on. It causes some fuzziness, if the resolution is low as you seem to have.

Answer (score 1):

Select your text then hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to bring up the 'Character' panel and play with the anti-aliasing option until it looks right. Probably need to choose the 'Smooth' option.

[image]