# Razor Sharp, Pixel Perfect Text Export from Illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, text, bitmap

I'm trying to create Windows 95 / 98 pixel perfect text styles to mockup a retro UI. In the past (roughly 8 years ago) I remember being able to export BMPs from Illustrator in Greyscale and get pixel perfect, razor sharp 8-bit text. Now (Adobe CC 2018) I'm getting anti-aliasing blurry edges with everything I try. I've tried 1-bit BMP, 4-bit, 8-bit, making sure the x and y coordinates are whole numbers, greyscale, Photshop Crisp, Strong, Sharp, etc. etc. etc. and nothing is working. Your help is appreciated!

Comment: Im not ure ui agree what pixel perfect means with you.

Answer (score 1):

in Photoshop:

Have your text in small size. Set anti-aliasing = NONE. Rasterize. Today pixels are quite small, so you must scale your image bigger. Do it with resampling mode = Nearest neighbour. That keeps the jagginess.

**In Illustrator** you can trace the jaggy upscaled image generated in Photoshop, if you need it as vector for free scaling to big sizes. This is discussed here: [Does anyone know how this kind of pixelated type is created?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/117957/does-anyone-know-how-this-kind-of-pixelated-type-is-created)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution in Photoshop - still haven't found an Illustrator export fix. I set the text appearance filter to 'none' in Photoshop and it gives the style that I was looking for, no anti-aliasing at all.

Comment: you can set illustrator export to no anti aliasing too.